# Getting scoring results for test&traing sets with SSAS data mining

Tags: machine-learning, ssas, regression

We have a quite **big table** and we are making predictions on it with SSAS data mining.

We are struggling to obtain the scored **test&train cases for validation** on an efficient manner. Is there a way to do it **without invoking** the algorithm for each of the lines (PREDICTION JOIN)?

By example, if my input data set has the following columns:

(Customer, Country, Age, Sex, BuyAmount) I want to obtain...

(Customer, Country, Age, Sex, BuyAmount, BuyAmountPredicted, Probability)

It has to be possible, since this is something done during model processing and it ir probably used to generate validation charts e.g. SystemGetClassificationMatrix.

If we are talking about billions of rows it will be a big performance improvement.

- Avoid double calculation (prediction join will execute the model for each line)
- Avoid moving data from DB to SSAS with openrowset (cases are already saved on model.cases)
- Avoid the need of writing the results back somewhere for future analysis

This is something that should be trivial to solve... I must be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I have got a solution coming from Microsoft. I am writing it here since it may be useful for someone else

The training/test data is stored in the mining structure, unless it’s cleared after training. The following queries should work:

SELECT Predict(..), PredictProbability(..) FROM MINING MODEL [ModelName]
NATURAL PREDICTION JOIN

Where  can be:
SELECT * FROM MINING STRUCTURE [MiningStructureName].CASES
SELECT * FROM MINING STRUCTURE [MiningStructureName].CASES WHERE IsTrainingCase()
SELECT * FROM MINING STRUCTURE [MiningStructureName].CASES WHERE IsTestCase()

To clear the cases from the mining structure
DELETE FROM MINING STRUCTURE [MiningStructureName].CASES

The mining structure training cases does not have the model filters applied to it. If you want to query the actual training cases that were sent to the model, you can either explicitly type the filter in the where clause or query the mining model cases directly (if the model has drillthrough enabled)
SELECT * FROM MINING STRUCTURE [MiningStructureName].CASES WHERE IsTrainingCase() and [Gender]=’Female’
SELECT * FROM MINING MODEL [ModelName].CASES

If the mining structure column names are different from the mining model column names, you have to use “PREDICTION JOIN’ instead of “NATURAL PREDICTION JOIN” and supply the mapping in the query.